# NAT timeout on particular websites. It feels like sites that contain re-direction for content in particular

Tags: networking, server, iptables, timeout

Problem Statement:

Desktop connected to LAN and WLAN encounter WWW **web timeout on specific web sites**.  This is Very consistent.  This occurs on Windows with Chrome and IE.  It also happens on the same sites with Android tablets & phone  (sorry no IOs at home... :-)).  If we wait long enough (several minutes) the site will eventually load.  Using w3m works just fine on Ubuntu server with troublesome sites.

Example: [www.meteomedia.com](http://www.meteomedia.com)
Chrome dispalys:

> Waiting   cdn.optimizely.com

but I can ping cdn.optimizely.com without any problem.  DNS resolves fine and ping response are fast.  Other sites will get stuck on

- cdn.optimizely.com
- media.richrelevance.com
- asstes.ado
- use.typekit.net

---

Home Setup

Modem

- ZyXel VSG1432-B101 as VDSL modem
- configuration as bridge only

Hardware

- Quad core server with 16G ram & 6 NICS
- ESXi 5.1 as OS on server.

VM #1 :

- Ubuntu Server 14.04 with 3 NICs
- eth0 - Bridge to Inernet
- ppp0 - PPPoE to Teksavvy.com via dryloop owned by Telus (in British Columbia) with Static IP address
- eth1 - User LAN 192.168.10.0/24
- eth2 - Voip LAN 192.168.11.0/24

History: 
I've ben using Linux servers as gateway since late '90 using Slackware distribution.  Moved to Ubuntu in 2008.  Using iptables for firewall (so just IPv4 firewall rules).

2008 - switch to Ubuntu.
2015 March - switched from ADSL to VDSL, everything working fine and speedy.
2015 July - timeout on certain web sites started.

I have identified the problem as being the Ubuntu Gateway because I have connected my laptop directly into the ZyXel Bridge and created a pppoe dialup with windows 7 and all the problematic sites worked just fine.

Further, right now I'm using the ZyXel as the router (instead of Ubuntu) and all web traffic is working fine, but my VPN, Voip system, camera,  are all down...

I have created a brand new 14.04 Server from scratch on my ESXI, and I've even tried a VERY simple firewall using iptables:

```
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables
DEPMOD=/sbin/depmod
MODPROBE=/sbin/modprobe
EXTIF="ppp0"
INTIF="eth1"
echo "External Interface:  $EXTIF"
echo "Internal Interface:  $INTIF"

$DEPMOD -a
$MODPROBE ip_tables
$MODPROBE ip_conntrack
$MODPROBE ip_conntrack_ftp
$MODPROBE ip_conntrack_irc
$MODPROBE iptable_nat
$MODPROBE ip_nat_ftp


echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_dynaddr

$IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F INPUT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD DROP
$IPTABLES -F FORWARD
$IPTABLES -t nat -F

$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $INTIF -o $EXTIF -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -j LOG

$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE
```

When using the laptop, I've noticed that Windows 7 was using an IPv6 as a DNS.  I thought that IPv6 might be the difference...  I've enabled IPv6 in bind and installed radvd on Ubuntu, that did not fix anything.  Actually it broke all my Androids, this is when I learned that Android does not support DHCP6.  I disabled radvd.

Tried:

- lowering MTU to 1200 on ppp0 and eth0
- enabling IPv6 DNS
- re building a new Ubuntu 14.04

---

I don't believe that anything changed on my gateway.  Althought I now remember that I've tried installing the ESXI VMWare tool that comes with ESXI and that failed miserably and may have broken something.  I've removed the extra bridges the install created.

Has anyone experienced such a thing?  I've seen many posts where people's browser got stuck on cdn.optimizely.com, but no real solution.  I've even tried disabling optimizely with

http://www.meteomedia.com/?optimizely_opt_out=true

and that did not fix anything (which is why I believe the problem is before) and might be in the redirection.

Kind Regards for any help,
Martin Politick.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the Zyxel VSG1432-B101 when in Bridge mode.
I'm posting this as informational only.

Solution:
Place Zyxel VSG1432-B101 in router mode
- then place Ubuntu behind the NAT as 192.168.1.2
- then set DMZ to be 192.168.1.2
- use Ubuntu as used in the past.

The problem with this solution is that my VPN is double NATed, 
once by the Zyxel, then by my Ubuntu server. It also frustrates me to the highest point that I was unable to get the Zyxel to work in Bridge mode...

I believe that the fact that I'm using the same firewall settings and the same Ubuntu server behind the routed Zyxel with no problem proves that the problem is in the Zyxel when it is in Bridge mode.
The only thing that is different is that I'm not using the PPPoE from Ubuntu, but the one from Zyxel.
The rest stayed identical...

The PPPoE from Ubuntu seem to work properly as I had great scores at the bandwidth tests and with most (simple) websites. The Zyxel did not show ANY problems on the VDSL statistics page even with Ubuntu.

Martin Politick 2015.